# cant reach deployed meteor project from my own domain

Tags: meteor

finally i could deploy my project with mupx and this mup.json:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "servers IP",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "blablabla",
      "env": {}
    }
  ],
  "setupMongo": false,
  "appName": "myApp",
  "app": "/var/www/vhosts/deploy.myApp",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 800,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myDomain",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://login:pass@d11111.mongdb.com:1111/myApp_com"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 120,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

i use `"PORT": 800` cuz i have plesk panel on the server, and with port 80 i got error:

```
x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Error response from daemon: no such id:
```

but after i change port, deploy went successfully.

but i still can't figure out how to rich my app from my domain?

actually i just find, that i can reach my app like this: http://mydomain:800/

but how to deploy on port 80 (which is standard for domain) if port 80 already busy to plesk panel?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy):

> In computer networks, a reverse proxy is a type of proxy server that retrieves resources on behalf of a client from one or more servers. These resources are then returned to the client as though they originated from the proxy server itself.

A server that will be listening to your port 80 and forward requests to appropriate application based on certain routing rules. One of the most popular solutions is nginx.

[This tutorial](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=70837.htm) provides information on how to install nginx with Plex. And meteorpedia has [a good article](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/nginx) on configuring nginx for meteor.

Comment: i already have plesk with apache + nginax, but i don't now how to configure nginax, i never did it before